# Join two mysql tables and get total sum value of two columns

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I have two almost identical structured tables with different data, in MySQL... I want to join those two tables and get the total sum of a column from both tables.

```
$fb_sql     = "SELECT campaign_name, adset_name, SUM(reach) AS reach, cpc, id_name, clicks, SUM(amount_spent) AS amount 
               FROM $table 
               WHERE id_campaign_shortname = '". $_GET["lpage"] ."' $where 
               AND date_from = '". $date_from ."' 
               AND date_to = '". $date_to ."' 
               GROUP BY id_name";

$google_sql = "SELECT campaign_name, SUM(reach) AS reach, cpc, id_name, clicks, SUM(amount_spent) AS amount 
               FROM google_msn_adwords_data 
               WHERE id_campaign_shortname = '". $_GET["lpage"] ."' 
               AND date_from = '". $date_from ."' 
               AND date_to = '". $date_to ."' 
               GROUP BY id_name";
```

But I want to join the two tables into one output, but with `SUM(reach)` and `SUM(amount_spent)` as a total value, f.x.
`fb_sql` the "reach" `SUM` is 400 and in `google_sql` the "reach" `SUM` is 450, my output for reach will be 850.

I am currently output the data with this:

```
$merged_data = array_merge($fb_result, $google_result);

$jsonArray = array();

if(count($merged_data) > 0) {

    $total = 0;

    foreach($merged_data as $elm) {

        array_push($jsonArray, array(
            "campaign" => array(
                "campaignName" => $elm["campaign_name"],
                "campaignAdsetName" => $elm["adset_name"],
                "campaignReach" => $elm["reach"],
                "campaignSpend" => $elm["amount"],
                "campaignCPC" => $elm["cpc"],
                "campaignClicks" => $elm["clicks"],
                "campaignId" => $elm["id_name"],
            )
        )
        );

        $total += $elm["reach"];

    }

$jsonCampaignDataArray = array("campaignData" => $jsonArray);
$jsonTotalReach = array("totalReach" => $total);

$finalArray = array_merge($jsonCampaignDataArray, $jsonTotalReach);

$json = json_encode($finalArray);

echo $_GET['jsoncallback']. '('. $json . ')';
```

But as described I want the "merge" to happen at MYSQL level as a single combined result.

Comment: Without knowing what the actual queries are, I find this kind of thing next to impossible, but presumably UNION might feature quite heavily in the answer.

Comment: Do you want it grouped and summed by id_name or no?

Comment: Yeah... I want it grouped by id_name

Answer (score 0):

you can use join query,

```
eg: SELECT bus.id, SUM( bus.type + rate.rating ) 
FROM  `business` bus
JOIN ratings rate ON rate.bus_id = bus.id where rate.bus_id=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

As per MySQL [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html):

> UNION is used to combine the result from multiple SELECT statements
>   into a single result set.

It would look like this:

```
(SELECT * FROM table1)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM table2);
```